# How do I solve my program's counting problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-parsing

(Apologies this is gonna be a long question)

I just have a bug in my code that I have not been able to resolve for a very long time. I would really appreciate if someone could help me find out what the problem is.

**Context:**
I have a long string of letters - lets call this `subject` - containing the letters A, G, T and C (like DNA) and the whole point of my algorithms is to correctly count how many of each of the following `STRs` are found within `subject`. The STRs are:

- `AGATC`
- `TTTTTTCT`
- `AATG`
- `TCTAG`
- `GATA`
- `TATC`
- `GAAA`
- `TCTG`

I must count how many of each are within `subject`. Counting works by going sequentially letter by letter until the start of one of above `STRs` are found. If the rest of the `STR` follows, the program should update the counter of the respective `STR` and then boost the searching index to account of the length of the `STR` and then keep going. It should stop when it reaches the end of `subject`.
(Hope it makes sense).

***My Code:***

```
STRs = ['AGATC','TTTTTTCT','AATG','TCTAG','GATA','TATC','GAAA','TCTG']
subject = "GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCGCTCGGCACGGCCTACACACGTCGTGTAACTACAACAGCTAGTTAATCTGGATATCACCATGACCGAATCATAGATTTCGCCTTAAGGAGCTTTACCATGGCTTGGGATCCAATACTAAGGGCTCGACCTAGGCGAATGAGTTTCAGGTTGGCAATCAGCAACGCTCGCCATCCGGACGACGGCTTACAGTTAGTAGCATAGTACGCGATTTTCGGGAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCCCGTCAACTCATTCACACCGCATCCTTTCCTGCCACTGTAACTAGTCGACTGGGGAACCTCATCATCCATACTCTCCCACATTATGCCTCCCAACCTTGTTAAGCGTGGCATGCTTGGGATTGCATTGATGCTTCTTGGAGAGGACGCTTTCGTTTTGGAGATTACAGGGATCCAATTTTATCATCGGTTCGACTCCCGTAACGACTTAGCAGTAAGGGTGCTAGTTCCTGGTTAGAATCTTAATAAATCACGTCGCTTGGAGCAAGACAAAGATCGTCGTAATGCCAAGTGCACGACCACCTTCAGACTTGCAGGACCCGTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTCGATAGCTATGCGGTTCAATACAATCTTAACGCAATGCAGCGATGTGGTTTCGTACACTTAGCATAAAACCCCCCACATTAAATCGATGTACCCGCCCTCTTAGACGCCAATTTCAATGCCGAACCTCCGGCGGGTATCTCTGCACTAGGAGAAGTAGCACGTCGCTGTAGCGAACTCCTATCGTGAGATAATTTGTAGAGCTGCTCTTATAATACAATAGCTCAGATGGATTATTCCATGGACATCCCCGTGCGTTGTTTCGAGGATGGTAGGTGGAAATTTTGCCAGACCTCTAGTCTTAAACATGGTTGACGTTATAGGCGCTATCTCTTGCGTCTGGAAGTGTTAATCCGTGAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAACACGCAACTCTGGAGGAGGGCACTGCACTGCAAACTTGCGTAATATCCTTCACCCACACTTGCCTGGCCTCCTTGCTTAAAGCTCTGGCGATGCGATTTTTCGGCCCAGTAGCTGAATAGGTCATGAAATGGGCACCGAACTGGAAAGACCCATATATTCGATACTCACAACTTAATGATAGCGCGATTAAGAGCGACACCAAAAACCAAATTACGTTCACGAACCTTTGAGAGTCAAGGAGACTTAGACCGAATTGAATGATCACTGATGCGCCCGCTGATACTGAGCCTCACCATTAATCGCCGACCAATACGGCGTGTACCGGGCGCGGCCTTGCCGCATAACGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATATCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTACACAGCCCCGTCCTCATTGCTAAGTGCACTGGCAACTGGACCTAAAGATTTTTCGAGTATGGCCCTCGAATCAAGCGCCCACCCAGAAACCTACGAGCCAGTAACCCCAGTAAACAAGCATTAGTGCTATATGCTTGCTGCCCACTAGGACCCTTATGGTTCATACCAGGGTGACGTGTCTTGCGGGCCAAGGATGAACCAGAAGCAAGATCCTTAGATGGACGACTGTCTCATTGCTTAAACTCCACATACCAAAGGGCGCGGTAAACGATAGTTTTAGGTAATGTTAGTCGGATGGTTGTCTGCAGCTACCAATACAGCCTGGCACCCAGGGTCTGAACAATAACGCGTGAGAGCAGCTCTCCCGCGTGTGGTGGATTTGCCGTCTATGAAATTGAGGCTCTTGCAACTATTCGCACTCGGAATGCCCTCATATCTGGTGCCTAGCGGCCTTTGCCCCGTGCCGGTAGGACTAAACTCTACGGATCGTTGACGGATCTCGATGTGGAAGATGGTTATGAAAGATAACAACGCGTGTGCTAATTGATTTAGACAAGTATTGCGGCAGTAAAAGATAATCGGCTGCAGAGTTACGAAAGACTTCCATGCATGGATTCCATTCCTTCTAGTATAGGACCCACTCTGAATACACGTCTTGCGGGCCGATCATCTCCACCGCTGCGGAAGAAAGCAATTAAGAATCTATGCTCATTAAGAGTGCGACTATAATGCGGATCTTACAGTGCTAATGATCAGGACGTCGTCCAAGCAGGCTGCATGCCGAATTTAGCTTACGTCAGGATCAGGCGTTATAGCCTGGGAATCGGACTATGAGGACGCCACGACCTCTGGGAGAAAGCTATATACATTGAGGATCGCGCCATCTTTATGAGACTCAAATGAATCTAGATAGGTAGCATTGCGGACTTGAGTTAGCACATCGGTATTGGAAGGTGAGGGTCCTGCCGCTCGTTCTATGTTCGGTTTATAGTATACAAATAGGTCATCCCGAACGTTGAAGTTAAACTCATGACACGTTGTCGTAATGAAACGGGCCTGTTATTAGGGATACAGACAAAAGGCACAAGCTGGCTTGCACATTAAGGCGCACTAGAGATCCTCACAACCGTTGCCCGCACGGAGGTCGTGTCTAACAGACAGTGAACCAGCCGTATTGGGGTGGATGACCTGAGCTTCTTGGGGCCTGTTGTACACCGCGTGTGGTTCAACTGGTACACATACTACGAATATTCGAAATCATTGTACTGTGCTCTTCGGTGCTACTGACTGTGAGCGAATGCATCCCAATCCCAAACAATGCTTGTGGTAGGAGAATTGAAACTCTCGAAGCCTGGCCCAATGTCATCTACTTTTAACATGTCGGGCCAGGAGTTACGGGCATTGCTTACTTACTTTGCCCCCTTACACCACAGCAGCGCGATTCTTGTTGTAGTAGATTTTATACGACTCGCGAATTAAATGGAACTTGTCTGTCCCATATCGATCGTGTCCATCGTAAGATGAGATTGTAGGAGCATTCGGAAGTCTATGCGGCCCAGGGACTACTACGTTAAATCTGGTCAGACGTGGTTTACAAGGCGTCCCGATCTTCTCAGAACATATGGGAAAGCACTACCGTTCCTTCACGCATACAGTTGTTCGTGCCGAACGAGTAAGCTTGCGACCAGCCCACCCGCTAGGGCTATGCAGCGGGTCATGGCTGGCGCCATACTGTGCGGACAACCCACGCTCTGGCAGAAAGCGTCTTGTGTTTTGTAGTAGCTCCAACGGTTAGACCTTCGATATCTATTCAGAGCGCGAGCGACCACTATTAGACGGCATGTAAACAATGTGTATTTGTTCGGCCCAACCGGTATATGGGTAAGACCGCGAAGGGCCTGCGCGAATACCAGCGTCCAAAAATTCCTCACCCGAGATATGCGGTTAGTACCCCTTGGGTAACGGTCCGCTACGGGTAGCGACGCGAGCCGGCCGCATCGGTTGGAGCCGAGTTGTCGGGCAGGCGAGTAACGTGTGCAATTTGATGGGCCCAAGCCTCCGGCACTATCCACCTCATACATCGACAAAAGCACCAAATATGGGGAAAAGCTGAGCGTCGATATGTACATCTACCCAGGAACCGGCCCGAACATTAGGCGGACGTGAATTTCCGACCTAGGTTCGGCTACATTTCTACGATCCAAGCACACGTGAAGGAGGAGGGGTGTTCCGACCGTAAATGAACGAGGTGCGCAGTGACCCGATGGCGTTTAGCGGATAGCCTTCCTATGCCGGCCTATGCTGTATGGTAGTTGGTTGGTGCCTCCAGAGCCACTGCACCCAATCATAGGGTCTACAGCAGCGTACTTATAAAATTGTACGGGTGACCCATATCCATTACGGGTTGCGACCAGTATAGGAGAGTATAACTGCGTGAACTAATGCGTTATGACGCTTCAGAGTTTGCTCGGGCCCGAGTTCTAGGGCTATAATGTGTTAGGGCGCAAGTATGCCAAGCTAAGATGTGGCGTGCACACTAGGAGTTGTGTTCCTCTGCAAGCAGACACGAGCACTCTGGCAGTAGTTTGACCACACCCGGGTATCACTGCTACTCCATTTCGAACAAGCTATTGGAGCGGACAAAATATGCTACTCAAGAGCATTAGTTATAGGTCTACGAGACAGAAGCAGTTACTGAGTCTGAATATTCGATATAAGTAGGCATGGAGGCGGAGCAAAACAACGTCTGCGATCAATCGTGTTGATGACGTATGGCGACTGGAAGGTAAGGACTATGGCCGGACGGAATGATTCATGTTCTGTTCAAAGCTATATTTCGAAGGGGTATATTAGCGGTCCTACACTTGGTTAGCACCCTCCCCCCTCTGGATCCTGCACTAATTCGAGCTGGCCTCCATCGGTATCAGTCCGGAAGCTCCACTCTCTATCGTAGTCCTAATCAACAGGGTGCCAGTTTGCTCACGTGGAAGTTTGAGGCCCTTTGTGCTCCATAGCCAATCACTAACCATGCACGCGCGACCCACTCTACGTCCAGATCGGCTATAATAGTTGCGCCCGGGACTGGCAGAGTAGACATGTAAGCTAGATAGAGCCCCGACATCGGCCAAGAGATCCTACGCTGCTTCCAGATAATGAGAGACATTCTAGCATTAGACATGCAAGTCGGCAGGGACTCCCCTTATCTAGTAATTTCGATGAATTGGTTTTTCGGCTAGCATCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGACCATGCCGACCTCATCATAGAAGGAATGCTCTAAACTTAGAGTGCTACTAGGAAAACTATTAATCAATGATCGTCCTGCTTACATAGCTGGACGGCGAAAGTTCTTATACTGCGGAGGTTGCTGACGTAGAGTGCGCTGGGTACAGCGGATAAGTTGATCAGGGTGGGGATAGGGTGGCTCACCGTTTATACTCATATAGATTCCTGGCGTCGACGCTGTGACAGGGTCGAGATCGAGGGGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGCGGAGCGGAGGGAAAATTATCACCAGAGGGTAGGGGCTCGCGACATTCTATTCAATGCATTTCAAGCTACTTACGTATTTCGGCACAGTGACTACTGCCTGCGCGGCAGCCGTAAGGTTTCCCGTCAATAGGTGGCACGTATCATTGATGAAAGTGTCAGCTAATCATTCAGGCCTTA"
x = 0 # Searching index.
dataSTR = { # All the STRs to seach for.
    "AGATC":0,
    "TTTTTTCT":0,
    "AATG":0,
    "TCTAG":0,
    "GATA":0,
    "TATC":0,
    "GAAA":0,
    "TCTG":0,
}
# This dict will hold all the count values of STR's in the text-file.
# Scanning STR's from the txt file.
total = len(subject)
limit = 8
while x < total:
    currentString = subject[x:x+limit] # A temporary variable to hold the next few letters from the text-file at index x.
    for STR in STRs:
        if STR in currentString: # The STR is found within this set of letters?
            lSTR = len(STR) - 1
            if STR[0:lSTR] == currentString[0:lSTR]: # In order to minimise the risk of duplication...
                dataSTR[STR] += 1 # ...the STR must be at the start of currentString.
                #print(currentString, STR, x, dataSTR[STR])
                x += lSTR # The index must be boosted each time a new STR is read. In the event that an STR is at the end of a stand...
    x += 1 # The index counts up by 1 by default. (From above) ...so that no duplicates are added.
print(dataSTR.items())
print("The correct result is: AGATC - 22, TTTTTTCT - 33, AATG - 43, TCTAG - 12, GATA - 26, TATC - 18, GAAA - 47, TCTG - 41")
```

(Sorry its very long, it might be helpful to copy into a separate python file).

As you will see from running it, the result my program brings up from counting is incorrect. The correct results are in the final print statement of the program, but the program does not match this (yes I know that these results are 100% correct since this is part of a problem set from an online computer science course).

However, I cannot seem to find the bug or logic error that seems to be causing my program to count wrong and I have been trying for quite a while now. Does anyone know what the solution is?

Please feel free to ask me anything about the program, thank you all.

Comment: Why not use `collections.Counter()`?

Comment: *"and then boost the searching index to account of the length of the STR"* - what if they overlap?

Comment: We have the problem that the question is ambiguous.  Does GATATC count as both a GATA and a TATC or do we only take the first one that we see.  Does TTTTTCTTTTTCT count as one or two occurrences?

Comment: The problem  is to get the max number of repeats for consecutive occurrences. I get 22 for `AGATC`.

Comment: Part of the solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125727/counting-repeated-str-in-dna-pset6-cs50/64126143?noredirect=1#comment113440602_64126143) in my post.

Comment: Thanks Chris Charley. I kinda understand what you and Michael Dyck are talking about. So instead for searching for STRs in a subset of subject, I should look for occurrences of the STR throughout subject? Is that the key here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem statement doesn't agree with the "correct results" given in your example code. Either you've misunderstood the problem, or you've taken the correct results from a different problem. (The "correct results" appear to be for the problem of finding the maximum number of *consecutive repeats* of each query string.) [The latter possibility is the point that Chris Charley makes in a comment on the original post.]

You can convince yourself by doing the problem "by hand": look at the subject string in a text editor, pick a query string, do a search on it, and step through the occurrences.

E.g., for the query string "GAAA", you'll count ~67 occurrences, but most of them are in a block of 47 repeats in subject[1449:1637]. (This is more obvious if you use a text editor that highlights all occurrences of the search string, as 188 characters of consecutive highlighting should jump out at you.) And 47 agrees with the "correct result" for GAAA.

Comment: Okay I kinda understand what you and Chris Charley are talking about? So instead for searching for STRs in a subset of `subject`, I should look for occurrences of the STR throughout `subject`?

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like you're trying to guess at how to alter your code in order to get the expected answers without understanding the problem you've been given. You have to understand the problem statement first.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
count_results = dict()
STRs = ['AGATC','TTTTTTCT','AATG','TCTAG','GATA','TATC','GAAA','TCTG']
subject = "loooong string..."

for search_string in STRs:
  count_results[search_string] = subject.count(search_string)

print(count_results)

{'AGATC': 28, 'TTTTTTCT': 33, 'AATG': 69, 'TCTAG': 18, 'GATA': 46, 'TATC': 36, 'GAAA': 67, 'TCTG': 60}
```

I realize the results are sometimes different to your expected counts, but I didn't go through the intricacies of your search algo and wonder if the expected output might be wrong? If not, check out the docs for the str.count() function, to see how & why it gets different output, and adapt what it does to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
import re
# Define STRs and subject here
dic = {}
for x in STRs:
  tv = len([m.start() for m in re.finditer(x,subject)])
  tv += 1
  dic[x] = tv

for y in dic.keys():
  print(y,dic[y])
```

Answer (score 1):

The results in the last print statement are incorrect. I checked it with python's built in method .count(), if you are allowed to use this method just use this one instead, but if not, I would recommend to do the following:

```
total = len(subject)
while x < total:
    for STR in STRs:
        limit = len(STR)
        currentString = subject[x:x+limit]
        if STR == currentString: 
            dataSTR[STR] += 1 
    x += 1
```

that way, you set the limit to the string's length so the STR is either exactly the string or not, so you don't have to check for duplicates. I don't know why your code didn't work, but I hope this will help you.